# ClearCase UCM: Is it possible to have a temporary view on any given baseline?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Is it possible to open a view (snapshot or dynamic, maybe readonly) on any given baseline (recommended or older) in a stream (integration, development or child) for performing some tasks and then remove the view when done? How?

Comment: What I need here is to be able to build a relsease from any given baseline, without changing anything inside the source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a view to a given baseline, you actually need a view associated to a *stream* with said baseline as a foundation baseline.

That means you need to rebase that stream first, which is:

- not always desirable (since you would need to merge said baseline with current content, and that doesn't always make sense)
- not always possible (you can only rebase a sub-stream with baselines coming from its immediate parent).

What is possible is to:

- get the stream on which your baseline has been put
- make a sub-stream from that stream, taking said baseline as the foundatio one
- create a snapshot or dynamic view on it
- do your work
- put a new baseline, and deliver it to its parent stream
- obsolete that sub-stream (and you can delete your view if you want)

---

Note: you could create a base ClearCase dynamic view (ie non-UCM) with a config spec you could then change as you want, but that wouldn't allow you to checkout and modify any file.
That would only be a convenient way to *visualize* any baseline of your choice.

Comment: Thanks VonC. Your answers were very helpful.